# Sending HTML email via Hangfire Postal

Tags: hangfire, ihtmlstring

In my app I have a rich text editor (tinyMCE). I want to take the HTML output from there and insert into a MVC Postal email object and schedule via Hangfire.

Whilst I have this process working as expected the Html is not rendering.

[image]

Unfortunately I can't use Html.Raw(string) as its not available when Hangfire runs.

I get the exception:

```
RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateCompilationException
```

Unable to compile template. The name 'Html' does not exist in the current context Other compilation errors may have occurred. Check the Errors property for more information.

RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateCompilationException: Unable to compile template. The name 'Html' does not exist in the current context

Other compilation errors may have occurred. Check the Errors property for more information.
   at RazorEngine.Compilation.DirectCompilerServiceBase.CompileType(TypeContext context) in c:\Users\abbottm\Documents\GitHub\RazorEngine\src\Core\RazorEngine.Core\Compilation\DirectCompilerServiceBase.cs:line 108
   at RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.CreateTemplateType(String razorTemplate, Type modelType) in c:\Users\abbottm\Documents\GitHub\RazorEngine\src\Core\RazorEngine.Core\Templating\TemplateService.cs:line 256
   at RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.GetTemplate[T](String razorTemplate, Object model, String cacheName) in c:\Users\abbottm\Documents\GitHub\RazorEngine\src\Core\RazorEngine.Core\Templating\TemplateService.cs:line 374
   at RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.GetTemplate(String razorTemplate, Object model, String cacheName) in c:\Users\abbottm\Documents\GitHub\RazorEngine\src\Core\RazorEngine.Core\Templating\TemplateService.cs:line 352

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean "wrapping commas"?

Comment: "<h1>This is a heading</h1> <p>This is a paragraph</p> "

Comment: Looking through dev tools in Chrome

Comment: Those are not commas. This is a comma: `,`. This is a double quote: `"`. And even if a double quote is wrapped around some HTML, then viewed in a browser, it will still render the result instead of the markup.

Comment: Doh, I am sorry. Quotes

Comment: I am not getting the html rendered. Instead I get the tags printed

Comment: Could it be something to do with the fact that the block is not wrapped in a tag at the view. I just render @Model.Message

Comment: Have you tried just `@Raw(Model.Message)` within your Postal view?

Comment: OK the quotes are because I hadn't specified  a tag in the view. I have nestled in a Div. I also Server Side created a new MvcHtmlString field based on the same html coming from SQL. This renders exactly the same as the string and shows the DOM tags instead of rendering them. Are there any alternative to using Html.Raw?

Comment: Did you follow my previous comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Postal uses [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine) to render the Razor views, you must use `@Raw(Model.Message)` if you want to directly add HTML to the view without it being escaped.